How to filter results to LLM from graph database based on source file names?
I'm trying to build a Graph RAG with hybrid retrieval for technical documentation files. The answers need to be found for version specific documentation files. I'm trying to achieve this by filtering graph and vector queries based on file names. However, I'm unable to implement source file filtering for Graph RAG implementations using Neo4j graph database.
Specifically, I started off by using the code sample given here:
text
and modified the code to load MS Word files. The code runs fine and the bot answers questions based on provided files. But, the bot is not picking up the right information from the right files for software version specific queries. So, I would like to limit the search space to information loaded on to the graph database from specific files. I tried modifying the graph database query (in the graph_retriever method) like this:
"""CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes('entity', $query, {limit:2})
            YIELD node,score
            CALL {
              WITH node
              MATCH (node)-[r:!MENTIONS]->(neighbor)
              WHERE node.source CONTAINS '12.34'
              RETURN node.id + ' - ' + type(r) + ' -> ' + neighbor.id AS output
              UNION ALL
              WITH node
              MATCH (node)<-[r:!MENTIONS]-(neighbor)
              WHERE node.source CONTAINS '12.34'
              RETURN neighbor.id + ' - ' + type(r) + ' -> ' +  node.id AS output
            }
            RETURN output LIMIT 50
            """

(added the WHERE clause in 2 places). But, if I do that, the graph_retriever function doesn't produce any results. I'm wondering whether a version_number field needs to be added to each entry in the graph database. But, in the above sample code, the add_graph_documents method doesn't allow storing URL or file name information for each entry in the graph database. How do I filter based on source file names in the sample code? I'm stuck. Any help is much appreciated.

The {limit: 2} argument to db.index.fulltext.queryNodes produces at most 2 nodes for the rest of your query to use.
Either remove the {limit: 2} argument entirely, or increase the 2 to a comfortably large enough number to make it much more likely that you get some nodes that match your WHERE filters.
